# Can you omit the @ when calling instance variables

Tags: ruby, variables

When you have a class with a attr_accessor, can't you omit the @ symbol when calling your instance variables since self.instance_variable would be implied if you don't use the @ symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`attr_accessor :foo`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) is basically just a macro that generates two methods (a getter and a setter) for you:

```
def foo
  @foo
end

def foo=(foo)
  @foo = foo
end
```

Can you omit the `@` when calling your instance variable? Kind of – calling the instance variable name without the `@` means you are calling the instance method generated by `attr_accessor` instead of calling the instance variable. This works as long as the getter method is not overridden or extended.

But when you would try to set an instance variable without the `@`, it would not work that way, because then Ruby would set a local variable with that name. To set the instance variable through the instance method generated by `attr_accessor` you need to write `self.` (or another receiver) instead of the `@`:

```
@foo = 'bar'      # assigns 'bar' to the instance variable `@foo`
foo = 'bar'       # assigns 'bar' to a local variable `@foo`
```

But to use the setter method generated by `attr_accessor`:

```
self.foo = 'bar'  # passes 'bar' to the instance method `foo=`
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case where you have an `attr_accessor` and you want to read the value, you'll get the same value. It isn't exactly that you're omitting the `@` but that you're calling a method with the same name that returns the instance variable.

Omitting the `@` when trying to set the value will not work the same way; it will just set a local variable with the same name. Using an object's setter within the object requires that you precede it with `self.`.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar

  def getter_equivalent?
    bar.equal?(@bar) # Returns true. They are the same object.
  end

  def set_with_at(value)
    @bar = value  # Will set the instance variable
  end

  def set_without_at(value)
    bar = value  # Will not set the instance variable
  end

  def set_with_self(value)
    self.bar = value  # Will set the instance variable
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

A class example with `attr_accessor` expanded for clarity. The usual `initialize` method has been omitted to focus on the task at hand:

```
class Foo

  def bar
    @bar
  end

  def bar=(bar)
    @bar = bar
  end    

  #the above two methods represent attr_accessor :bar      

  def call_method
    bar
    #same as self.bar
    #self refers to the current object i.e. the current instance of Foo
    #bar refers to the method bar defined above
  end
    
  def call_instance_var
    @bar
    #refers directly to the the instance variable
  end
end
```

You can use either one, I personally prefer calling the method rather than the instance variable.

#### Example

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.bar = "bar"
foo.call_method       #=> "bar"
foo.call_instance_var #=> "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it's possible to use accessor methods within the class, it's better practice to use the `@` symbol to refer to instance variables.

Here's an example where using a reader method within a class would produce unexpected results:

```
class A

  def var
    @var
  end

  def defined_using_method?
    defined?(var)
  end

  def defined_using_at?
    defined?(@var)
  end

end

A.new.defined_using_method? # => "method"
A.new.defined_using_at? # => nil
```